# Keyboard shortcut to move focus to a tab within a dialogue box?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

Without boring you with the details as to why I need this...

In Windows XP, if you have a settings/options dialogue box open that has several tabs, each containing its own controls, is there a keyboard shortcut to move the focus up to the tab itself i.e. so there's a dotted line around it?

Comment: I think it's better if you give more detail on why you need this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a standard keyboard shortcut that will accomplish this with a single press all the time.

**However, it is possible to cycle through the different property sheets (tabs) at any time even though none of the tabs have the focus (dotted outline):**

- Cycle to text tab: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Cycle to previous tab: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

**If you really need the tabs to have that dotted outline (focus), the tabs are included in the <kbd>Tab</kbd>-order, so they will eventually have the focus by cycling through the <kbd>Tab</kbd>-order of all the UI elements on the property sheet:**

- Cycle to next dialog element: <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Cycle to previous dialog element: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your response but I was aware of those two things but they don't do what I need. I need this for a macro recorder/player I'm using so wouldn't be doing it 'live' and therefore not able to spot when the focus cycles round to the tab.